# I need to count how many active "things" the user had per month

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a database structured like this

| USER_ID | THING_ID | CREATED_AT | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| userid1 | thingid1 | jan | activated |
| userid1 | thingid2 | jan | activated |
| userid1 | thingid1 | feb | canceled |
| userid1 | thingid3 | mar | activated |
| userid1 | thingid3 | mar | activated |
| userid1 | thingid3 | apr | canceled |
| userid1 | thingid3 | may | activated |

btw the date isnt just the month is a full date, I used that for the example

I need to count how many active "things" each user (I put only 1 for the example) had per month... so the results looked something like this

| USER_ID | month | ACTIVE "THINGS" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| userid1 | jan | 2 |
| userid1 | feb | 1 |
| userid1 | mar | 3 |
| userid1 | apr | 2 |
| userid1 | may | 3 |

I've tried was using row_numbers and LAG... it didnt work obviusly, or i did it wrong

Answer (score 1):

this could be done using a simple `countif` in BigQuery.

Your query could be something like this:

```
select userId, month, countif(STATUS="activated") from your_table group by 1,2
```

Here is the countif documentation on BQ: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators

Comment: the problem with contif is it will not deduct 1 if a thing got canceled